# add values on a negative pandas df based on condition date

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe which contains credit of a user, each row is how much credit has a given day.

A user loses 1 credit per day.

I need a way to code that if a user has accumulated credit **in the past** will fill all the days that credit was 0.

An example of refilling past credits:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

data = pd.DataFrame({'credit':[0,0,0,2,0,0,1],'date':pd.date_range('01-01-2021','01-07-2021')})
data['credit_after_consuming'] = data.credit_refill -1
```

Looks like:

```
|    |   credit_refill | date                |   credit_after_consuming |
|---:|----------------:|:--------------------|-------------------------:|
|  0 |               0 | 2021-01-01 00:00:00 |                       -1 |
|  1 |               0 | 2021-01-02 00:00:00 |                       -1 |
|  2 |               0 | 2021-01-03 00:00:00 |                       -1 |
|  3 |               2 | 2021-01-04 00:00:00 |                        1 |
|  4 |               0 | 2021-01-05 00:00:00 |                       -1 |
|  5 |               0 | 2021-01-06 00:00:00 |                       -1 |
|  6 |               1 | 2021-01-07 00:00:00 |                        0 |
```

The logic should be as you can see the three first days the user would have credit -1, until the 4th of January, where the user has 2 days of credit, one used that day and the other one is consumed the 5.

In total there would be 3 days(the first one without credits).

If at the start of the week a user picks 7 credits it is covered all week.

Another case would be

```
|    |   credit_refill | date                |   credit_after_consuming |
|---:|----------------:|:--------------------|-------------------------:|
|  0 |               2 | 2021-01-01 00:00:00 |                        1 |
|  1 |               0 | 2021-01-02 00:00:00 |                       -1 |
|  2 |               0 | 2021-01-03 00:00:00 |                       -1 |
|  3 |               0 | 2021-01-04 00:00:00 |                       -1 |
|  4 |               1 | 2021-01-05 00:00:00 |                        0 |
|  5 |               0 | 2021-01-06 00:00:00 |                       -1 |
```

In this case the participant would run out of credits the 3rd and 4th day, because it has 2 credits the 1st, one consumed the same day and then the 2nd.
Then the 5th would refill and consume the same day, to run out of credits the 6th day.

I feel it's like some variation of cumsum but I can-t manage to get the expected results.
I could do a sum all days and fill the 0's with those accumulated, but I have to take into account I can only refill with credits accumulated in the past.

Comment: I do not understand the part of `credit_refill` is `2`. Shouldn't the `credit_after_consuming` on the 5th day be `0`? Why it is `-1`. The same question for the second example too, if on Jan-01 is given `2` credit, then why on Jan-02, `credit_after_consuming` is `-1`. I suppose it should be `0`?

Comment: That is how it should be indeed! The 2nd of January should be 0 because the rewards are accumulated, credit_after_consuming column is just a credit_refill - 1 three is no extra computation.

Comment: Sorry but I still have no idea what you want to do. Maybe `cumsum` is the function you are looking for. Hope this helps